# TypeError: my_function() takes exactly 4 arguments (5 given)

Tags: python, json, forms

I don't know why it's not working; it returns this error:

```
TypeError: create_selected_properties_json_doc() takes exactly 4 arguments (5 given)
```

Code:

```
def another_function():

    confirmed_diagnostic_keys = [some, keys]
    generalized_stage_keys = [some, keys]
    stage_acording_to_uicc_keys = [some, keys]

    self.create_selected_properties_json_doc(self, form, 'hallelluja', confirmed_diagnostic_keys)
    self.create_selected_properties_json_doc(self, form, 'mashalla', generalized_stage_keys)
    self.create_selected_properties_json_doc(self, form, "heheeyy", stage_acording_to_uicc_keys)


 def create_selected_properties_json_doc(self, form, json_obj_key, form_element_ids):

        # Create an empty dictionary
        json_obj[json_obj_key] = {}

        #Loop through the keys in list
        for key in form_element_ids:

            #check if the keys matches any of form's key
            if key in form:

                #Add values of form elements to the dictionary properties
                json_obj[json_obj_key][key] = form[key]
            else:
                # Otherwise add "Jo" to the respective dictionary property
                json_obj[json_obj_key][key] = 'NO'

        return json_obj
```

Comment: `self` is passed implicitly, you don't need to do it manually - you're effectively calling `Class.method(self, self, ...)`.

Answer (score 4):

Do not pass `self` as the first argument:

```
self.create_selected_properties_json_doc(form, 'hallelluja', confirmed_diagnostic_keys)
```

`self.create_selected_properties_json_doc` is a [*bound* method](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects). When called, `self` is passed as the first argument to `create_selected_properties_json_doc` automatically, so you should only pass the rest of the arguments.

---

To avoid the `NameError: global name 'json_obj' is not defined`, you need to define `json_obj` in `create_selected_properties_json_doc`:

```
def create_selected_properties_json_doc(self, form, json_obj_key, form_element_ids):
    json_obj = dict()
    # Create an empty dictionary
    json_obj[json_obj_key] = {}
```

To store the dict returned by `create_selected_properties_json_doc` in `another_function`, assign it to a variable:

```
def another_function():

    confirmed_diagnostic_keys = [some, keys]
    generalized_stage_keys = [some, keys]
    stage_acording_to_uicc_keys = [some, keys]

    json1 = self.create_selected_properties_json_doc(
        form, 'hallelluja', confirmed_diagnostic_keys)
    json2 = self.create_selected_properties_json_doc(
        form, 'mashalla', generalized_stage_keys)
    json2 = self.create_selected_properties_json_doc(
        form, "heheeyy", stage_acording_to_uicc_keys)
```

Comment: what value do I have to return in function another_function() because if I return json_obj it shows me the error: NameError: global name 'json_obj' is not defined, because of self argument I didnt paas in function create_selected_properties_json_doc()

Comment: What is `json_obj`? It is not defined in any of the code you posted.

Comment: json_obj is the return of function create_selected_properties_json_doc(), wich means it's a json object. so I dont know how to return json_obj at another_function()

Answer (score 1):

When passing arguments to a function avoid passing the self(Which is object reference and passed automatically self is passed implicitly, you don't need to do it manually.

Example: Its just for to make you understand.

```
def binary_search(self,input_array,left_index,right_index):
    mid=left_index+(right_index-left_index)/2
    return mid
def call_function(self,*arg):
    self.binary_search(input_array,left_index,right_index) #self is not 
                                                           passed
```